# Alter Memory Optimized SQL Server 2014 Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Can I alter my memory optimized table? Like adding column or changing data types etc. If yes, how to do it?
I am using SQL Server 2014

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`Altering Memory-Optimized Tables (SQL Server 2014)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269114%28v=sql.120%29.aspx):

> **Performing ALTER operations on memory-optimized tables is not
>   supported.** This includes such operations as changing the bucket_count,
>   adding or removing an index, and adding or removing a column. This
>   topic provides guidelines on how to update memory-optimized tables.
>
> **Updating the definition of a memory-optimized table requires you to create a new table with the updated table definition, copy the data to the new table, and start using the new table.**

But it will be possible with [`SQL Server 2016`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269114%28v=sql.130%29.aspx):

> In SQL Server 2016 Community Technology Preview 2 (CTP2) you can
>   perform ALTER operations on memory-optimized tables by using the ALTER
>   TABLE statement. The database application can continue to run, and any
>   operation that is accessing the table is blocked until the alteration
>   process is completed.
>
> In the previous release of SQL Server, you had to manually complete
>   several steps to update memory-optimized tables.